# Flatpak - local repository - deleting export

Tags: repository, local, flatpak

I have a local repository with some content that can be seen using:

```
$ flatpak remote-ls tutorial-repo
```

I one to delete one of the references in the repository. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Another way of seeing the branches available in the local repository is:

```
$ flatpak repo --branches repo/
```

In orther to delete one of those branches you would do (as an exmaple):

```
$ flatpak --user uninstall app/org.freedesktop.Myapp/x86_64/master
```

Comment: The question is how to remove a flatpak export from a repo, not how to uninstall a flatpak application from the system. I was looking for the same as I manage a repo and wanted to remove an export without rebuilding the entire repo. But I don't think it's possible.